# Pandas: how to merge to dataframes on multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes, `df1` and `df2`.

`df1` Contains the information of some interactions between people.

```
df1
     Name1   Name2 
0    Jack    John   
1    Sarah   Jack   
2    Sarah   Eva    
3    Eva     Tom    
4    Eva     John
```

`df2` Contains the status of general people and also some people in `df1`

```
df2
     Name     Y 
0    Jack     0   
1    John     1   
2    Sarah    0       
3    Tom      1 
4    Laura    0
```

I would like `df2` only for the people that are in `df1` (Laura disappears), and for those that are not in `df2` keep `NaN` (i.e. Eva) such as:

```
df2
     Name     Y 
0    Jack     0   
1    John     1   
2    Sarah    0       
3    Tom      1 
4    Eva     NaN
```

Comment: Please share your dfs as `df.to_dict()`

Answer (score 2):

Create a [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) on unique values of `df1` and [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) it with `df2` as:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.unique(df1.values),columns=['Name'])
df['Y'] = df.Name.map(df2.set_index('Name')['Y'])

print(df)
    Name    Y
0    Eva  NaN
1   Jack  0.0
2   John  1.0
3  Sarah  0.0
4    Tom  1.0
```

**Note :** Order is not preserved.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of unique names in df1 and use isin

```
names = np.unique(df1[['Name1', 'Name2']].values.ravel())
df2.loc[~df2['Name'].isin(names), 'Y'] = np.nan

    Name    Y
0   Jack    0.0
1   John    1.0
2   Sarah   0.0
3   Tom     1.0
4   Laura   NaN
```